# Can't get Owl Carousel animation to work for Wordpress theme?

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I'm new here and new to development, so please excuse me if this is a total noob question. I'm currently developing a personal theme on Wordpress. I started with Bootstrap 4, and have had a fairly easy time figuring out the basics. I have my design and layout where I want it, and now I am trying to add in some functionality. I'm trying to implement Owl Carousel in my header with my recent blog posts. I am basing my carousel off of this code I found: https://codepen.io/bootstrapped/pen/wWQzPd

Here are the steps I took to implement my carousel:

I downloaded Owl Carousel and uploaded the js and css files to my theme's directory. I then created a file called slider.js in which I placed this code:

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    var owl = $("#owl-demo-2");
      owl.owlCarousel({
      items : 3, 
      itemsDesktop : [992,3],
      itemsDesktopSmall : [768,2], 
      itemsTablet: [480,2], 
      itemsMobile : [320,1]
    });
    $(".next").click(function(){ owl.trigger('owl.next'); });
    $(".prev").click(function(){ owl.trigger('owl.prev'); });

    $('.latest-blog-posts .thumbnail.item').matchHeight();

    });
```

I then added this code to my functions.php to enqueue the scripts and styles:

```
function owl_carousel_style() {
    wp_enqueue_style(
        'owl-carousel', 
        get_template_directory_uri().'/css/owl.carousel.css',
        array(), '1.0'
    );
}
function owl_carousel_script() {
    wp_enqueue_script(
        'owl-carousel', 
        get_template_directory_uri().'/js/owl.carousel.js',
        array( 'jquery' ), 
        '1.0',
        true
    );
    wp_enqueue_script(
        'owl-carousel', 
        get_template_directory_uri().'/js/slider.js'
    );
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'owl_carousel_style');
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'owl_carousel_script');
```

I then added my styles to my style.css file and added this html to my header.php which is where I wanted the carousel to appear:

```
    <section class="latest-blog-posts bg-white pt60 pb60">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div id="owl-demo-2" class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
            <article class="thumbnail item" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/CreativeWork">
            <a class="blog-thumb-img" href="/5-ways-baby-boomers-changing-healthcare/" title="">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/500x250" class="img-responsive" />
            </a>
            <div class="caption">
                <h4 itemprop="headline">
        <a href="#" rel="bookmark">5 Ways Baby Boomers Are Changing Healthcare</a>
      </h4>
                <p itemprop="text" class="flex-text text-muted">5 ways baby boomers are changing healthcare Starting in 2011, 3 million baby boomers each year reach retirement age....</p>
            </div>
        </article>

        <article class="thumbnail item" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/CreativeWork">
            <a class="blog-thumb-img" href="/5-ways-baby-boomers-changing-healthcare/" title="">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/500x250" class="img-responsive" />
            </a>
            <div class="caption">
                <h4 itemprop="headline">
        <a href="#" rel="bookmark">5 Ways Baby Boomers Are Changing Healthcare</a>
      </h4>
                <p itemprop="text" class="flex-text text-muted">5 ways baby boomers are changing healthcare Starting in 2011, 3 million baby boomers each year reach retirement age asdf asdfas dfasd fasdf asdf asfasdf asdf....</p>
            </div>
        </article>

        <article class="thumbnail item" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/CreativeWork">
            <a class="blog-thumb-img" href="/5-ways-baby-boomers-changing-healthcare/" title="">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/500x250" class="img-responsive" />
            </a>
            <div class="caption">
                <h4 itemprop="headline">
        <a href="#" rel="bookmark">5 Ways Baby Boomers Are Changing Healthcare</a>
      </h4>
                <p itemprop="text" class="flex-text text-muted">5 ways baby boomers are changing healthcare Starting in 2011, 3 million baby boomers each year reach retirement age....</p>
            </div>
        </article>

        <article class="thumbnail item" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/CreativeWork">
            <a class="blog-thumb-img" href="/5-ways-baby-boomers-changing-healthcare/" title="">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/500x250" class="img-responsive" />
            </a>
            <div class="caption">
                <h4 itemprop="headline">
        <a href="#" rel="bookmark">5 Ways Baby Boomers Are Changing Healthcare</a>
      </h4>
                <p itemprop="text" class="flex-text text-muted">5 ways baby boomers are changing healthcare Starting in 2011, 3 million baby boomers each year reach retirement age....</p>
            </div>
        </article>

        <article class="thumbnail item" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/CreativeWork">
            <a class="blog-thumb-img" href="/5-ways-baby-boomers-changing-healthcare/" title="">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/500x250" class="img-responsive" />
            </a>
            <div class="caption">
                <h4 itemprop="headline">
        <a href="#" rel="bookmark">5 Ways Baby Boomers Are Changing Healthcare</a>
      </h4>
                <p itemprop="text" class="flex-text text-muted">5 ways baby boomers are changing healthcare Starting in 2011, 3 million baby boomers each year reach retirement age....</p>
            </div>
        </article>

        <article class="thumbnail item" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/CreativeWork">
            <a class="blog-thumb-img" href="/5-ways-baby-boomers-changing-healthcare/" title="">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/500x250" class="img-responsive" />
            </a>
            <div class="caption">
                <h4 itemprop="headline">
        <a href="#" rel="bookmark">5 Ways Baby Boomers Are Changing Healthcare</a>
      </h4>
                <p itemprop="text" class="flex-text text-muted">5 ways baby boomers are changing healthcare Starting in 2011, 3 million baby boomers each year reach retirement age....</p>
            </div>
        </article>
    </div><!-- #owl-demo-2 -->
```

```
</div><!-- .container -->

</section>
```

Lastly, I linked my stylesheets at the bottom of my footer.php. I'm having trouble formatting the code, so here is a screenshot. 
[footer.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/svy9c.jpg)

After doing all of this, the carousel appears on my page. The styling is more or less correct, and it is responsive. The only issue is the animation will not work. When I press the forward/backward icons, nothing happens. Something is telling me there's an issue with the slider.js file or where I've linked the stylesheets, but I've messed around with it and am having no luck. Here's another screenshot, so you can see what it looks like. [Carousel Screenshot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gvFoo.jpg) Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Just as a note, the first parameter of `wp_enqueue_script`function is an id of the script you are enqueuing. If you have multiple with the same name the last one will be enqueued only. And can you get back with the error message telling about the issue in slider.js?

Comment: Thank you for your response. I corrected the parameter error you mentioned within my functions.php. Even after fixing that though, the animation is still not working. And I'm not receiving an error from slider.js, I just had a hunch that something may be off with the code. Sorry if that's not much help.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to download owl carousel required files from there official website.
put .min file in assets/CSS and use the javascript under the footer file in your root directory using.   tags and your owl carousel will work fine you can manage your items as per your requirements.